# Colorinformation of ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

For a given plot (unknown Colorfunction) `bild` I would like to get the color of every single point `{x,y,z}`.

```
bild = ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], 
Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

I tried

```
pts=bild[[1, 1]][[1]]
Cases[ bild , VertexColors -> col_  :> col, -1] (* { } *)
```

which returns an empty set.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It may help to try with `bild = ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
   Contours -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], 
  Mesh -> False,PlotPoints->5]`

Comment: it seems then this works? tt = bild // FullForm // First // First // First;
pts = tt[[1]]; 
col = tt[[3, 2]];
Transpose[{col, Map[Point, pts]}] // Graphics3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also works but is probably less robust. It does not require redoing the plot though.

```
tt = bild // FullForm // First // First // First; 
pts = tt[[1]]; col = tt[[3, 2]]; 
Transpose[{col, Map[Point, pts]}] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. `VertexColor` only gives a scalar as color information, I would have expected an RGB-triple Any idea how to interpret this scalar?

Comment: I am not sure I understand: `col[[1]] // Head` returns `Hue`.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I can reproduce your result!

Answer (score 5):

You may try with `Sow` and `Reap`.

```
{bild, pts} = 
  Reap[ContourPlot3D[
    x^3 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z}, Sow[{Hue[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], {x, y, z}}]; 
      Hue[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], Mesh -> False]];

Graphics3D[MapAt[Point, First@pts, {All, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer!

Comment: It is astonishing that ContourPlot3D generates far fewer points here than in  chris's answer

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I believe he set `PlotPoints -> 50` (which I did not) – that's why he got more points :)

Answer (score 4):

```
stylePointPairs = Cases[Normal[bild], 
   Polygon[coords_, VertexColors -> cols_, ___] :> 
    Thread[{cols, Point /@ coords}], All];

Graphics3D[{PointSize@Medium, stylePointPairs}]
```

[image]

You can also use:

```
stylePointPairs2 = Cases[bild, 
   GraphicsComplex[coords_, ___, VertexColors -> cols_, ___] :> 
    Thread[{cols, Point /@ coords}], All];

Graphics3D[{PointSize@Medium, stylePointPairs2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Normal[bild] /. 
  {_Line -> {}, 
  Polygon[coords_, vc : (VertexColors -> _), ___] :>
    {PointSize @ Medium, Point[coords, vc]}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any idea why `Cases[ bild , VertexColors -> col_  :> col, -1]` doesn't work?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, we need to use   `Cases[bild, (VertexColors -> col_) :> col, -1]` or `Cases[bild, HoldPattern[(VertexColors -> col_)]:> col, -1]`

Comment: Check `VertexColors -> col_ :> col // FullForm` to see how `VertexColors -> col_  :> col` is parsed.